# Pushing to floating-point registers instead of stack

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

I have a function that needs to be as fast as possible, and it uses only integer operations. It runs on the AMD64 architecture, and I need to do a few push/pops in order to have enough registers to work with. Now I'm wondering, the x64 ABI states that the first four floating-point registers (XMM0, XMM1, XMM2, and XMM3) are volatile and do not need to be preserved across function calls.

So I figured I could store the 64-bit registers I need to preserve in the lower 64 bits of those registers (i.e. MM0, MM1, ...) via movq (MMX or SSE instruction set) instead of using the stack, saving myself a few memory load/stores. Furthermore I wouldn't need to store the FPU state using EMMS - which would defeat the purpose - since I am not actually manipulating the floating-point registers but only using them as storage (and anyway, the x87 unit is hardly used at all under x64, as it is essentially superseded by SSE)

I have done the modification and it works (no crashes, and an observable 4% increase in performance), but I am wondering, does this "hack" really work or would it introduce any particular side effects I might have missed (like FPU state corruption even though I don't use it, that sort of thing). And will load/storing to an FPU register always be faster than a memory load/store on any current architecture?

And, yes, this optimization is *really* needed. And to be fair, this isn't something that would severely degrade code maintenance cost, a one-line comment would be enough to explain the trick. So if I can get a couple less clocks per byte for free with no unintended consequences, I'll gladly take them :)

Thanks.

Comment: If you're storing it in MM registers, why does it matter whether the first 4 XMM registers are volatile?

Comment: @harold: because otherwise I'd have to push and pop the XMM registers in order to not violate the ABI, which would defeat the purpose of avoiding memory load/stores in the first place. I think.

Comment: You wouldn't need to do that in any case - the MM registers don't overlap with the XMM registers..

Comment: @harold So I should be using the XMM registers then, to leave the FPU alone, right? I will do that instead. Thanks. Really, I shouldn't ever need to push to the stack with sixteen XMM registers!

Comment: Actually using the XMM registers yields no benefit since they're already being pushed/popped by the callee (unfortunately), so it looks as if I'm stuck with MM registers. It should do, though.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. If you use the MM registers, then the EMMS instruction becomes relevant again. You might be able to get away with not calling it, if you're sure no x87 operations will be called, but it gets a bit trickier to ensure correctness, at least, if you use the MM registers, and want to avoid the EMMS call

Comment: I guess I could let the user deal with it by calling EMMS after he's done using my function (since it will usually be used many times in a row) if he is doing x87 work after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EMMS instruction is only necessary to clear the state after MMX operations. SSE instructions do not require it. So that certainly won't conflict.

Of course, you should keep in mind that different compilers and OS'es use different calling conventions, and some may treat those four registers differently.

However, as long as that is kept in mind, I don't see a problem with this approach. You're using all registers the way they're supposed to be used according to the ABI.

And assuming this is written in assembly, there's no need to consider whether this may hinder compiler optimization (a C/C++ function which dives into ASM and starts talking about specific registers makes it a lot harder for the compiler to optimize the code)

Comment: I thought 64-bit only had one calling convention (in an effort to increase compatibility, presumably), but I will check again in more depth. Indeed this approach will break if a different convention doesn't treat the first four SSE registers as volatile.

Comment: @Thomas Windows uses a different convention than Linux, sadly. I'm not sure why they diverge, and, to be honest, the one Microsoft chose to use looks really damn stupid (effectively *never* pass SIMD values in XMM registers. Always push them onto the stack)

Comment: And yes it is written as a pure assembler subroutine, so compilers don't need to look into it and can treat it as a black box.

Comment: That might explain why my code failed under Ubuntu, then (it was just a quick and dirty test and I wasn't planning to look into it just yet). Hopefully the approach will still work (perhaps with some minimal platform-specific tweaks). Sad that Windows and Linux can never agree fully, makes cross-compilation incredibly tedious.

Comment: @jalf [`__vectorcall`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_vectorcall) was introduced in MSVC2013 to fix some of those flaws